# Fix jagged edges of a BufferedImage made from 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, bufferedimage, antialiasing

I am trying to make BufferedImages with color data stored in a 2D array.  It works, but I was wondering if there was a simple way to fix the jagged, saw-tooth-like, edges.

[image: Anti-alias]

I am guessing there may be an API or a simple trick this, but I been looking at numerous Java Docs to no avail.  Vector Magic does do what I am looking for, but I want to learn how to code this on my own.

Comment: Image processing is anything but simple.  The term you need to search with is anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in a quick way to just "turn on" anti-aliasing capabilities, then you may be able to take advantage of the Java2D APIs for [Controlling Rendering Quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html).  You can pass options in the form of [`RenderingHints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) by calling [`Graphics2D#setRenderingHints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHints(java.util.Map)).  One of the available hints is to request anti-aliasing.

The following code sample displays 2 windows that both draw the same circle, one with the anti-aliasing option off, and the other with the anti-aliasing option on.  If you look closely, you'll see that the one generated with the anti-aliasing rendering hint is less jaggy.

## TestAntiAliasing.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestAntiAliasingPanel extends JPanel {

    private final RenderingHints rh;

    private TestAntiAliasingPanel(RenderingHints rh) {
        this.rh = rh;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fillOval(50, 50, 300, 300);
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 50, 50, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createFrameWithAntiAliasingOption(false);
        createFrameWithAntiAliasingOption(true);
    }

    private static void createFrameWithAntiAliasingOption(boolean antiAliasingOption) {
        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                antiAliasingOption ? RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON :
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestAntiAliasingPanel(rh));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Compile with `javac TestAntiAliasingPanel.java` and then run with `java TestAntiAliasingPanel`.

> ...but I want to learn how to code this on my own.

If you're really interested in learning how to code the buffer manipulations to do the anti-aliasing yourself directly, then this is a big topic that would require external research.  As a starting point, [Wikipedia has articles on several anti-aliasing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anti-aliasing_algorithms).